# Export Data from Access 365 to IBM i-Series v7r1

Tags: vba, ms-access, db2, db2-400

Has anyone had success with this?

1.) I'd like to design tables and forms in Access 365 as a UI.

2.) Create a NEW inventory Transaction batch table (Inventory Transaction Batch Header and Inventory Transaction Detail Items) on the IBM i-series.

3.) "Post" the transactions to the Inventory Transaction Detail Items
4.) save and close the batch.

I currently have a "read-only" permission to get data FROM the i-Series and import it into access using ODBC, but I'd like to know if there is a way to "write" data into the 2 tables related tables as mentioned above.

Both the batch header table and the transaction detail table use a generated (unique) sequential number, so I'm thinking that the highest values would have to be "looked up" as well as locking the new values so that they could not be re-used by another user.

Just "Difficult" or "Impossible"?

Answer (score 2):

first off - realize that v7r1 is 10+ years old, and has been out of support for a while...you are likely to run into driver issues, especially if running on supported versions of Windows.

ODBC is bi-directional...writing is just as easy as reading.  But you'll need write permission, aka *CHG authority to the table.

It's been years, but IIRC you can use an Access linked table to read/write directly to the table on the i.  But I wouldn't recommend it for large (or important) tables.

One thing that usually trips up newbies is that by default ODBC tries to use transactions, aka commitment control.  For that to work, the tables must be journaled on the i.  Or you can set the commit level to *NONE on your connection.

I've created VBA applications in the past in older versions of Access that use SQL to write to IBM i tables.  I assume that is all still possible.  But you might want to write to some sort of staging table, then have a process move the data to the production table.

Honestly, if you know any other languages...I'd reconsider using Access at all.

> generated (unique) sequential

If it's actually generated, aka an SQL identity column, then it shouldn't be an issue, when you do the insert, don't specify that column and the DB will generate the next value.

However, older applications on the IBM i are unlikely to actually be using an identity column.  If you're lucky, the sequence number will be stored in some other table that you can read and update.

If the sequence is stored in a data area, you'll probably need an (external) SQL Stored procedure written to interact with it.